# Groups List on Communities Force.com Page showing differently for Admin and Customer?

Tags: community, customer-portal, customer-community, chatter-groups

Summary: **I am trying to solve a situation where an admin user sees "my groups" on the communities page, but a portal user see's their cases instead.**

*Details:*

I have a tab in my portal which is called My Team (Page: Group List, screen shot of navigation builder here):

[image]

When I click this as an admin in preview mode, I am routed where I expect:

[image]

And I see "My Groups" view (as I expect!):

[image]

But it I hit that same tab as a community user, I go to the same URL, but the page is my case list....

[image]

I've made sure the nav bar page is setup as "Publicly Available" - but obviously there's somewhere I need to be providing a My Groups list to community users -  can someone let me know what I am missing, and/or let me know what other info I can provide here to help?

Thanks so much in advance!
Shamir